# IN_VND_ITM_XLS Excel to CI - New field added to CI does not get inserted

Tags: peoplesoft

I have added a new field into the IN_VND_ITM_XLS component interface, (BU_PRICE_STATUS), which is in a SQL View already part of the delivered template, ITM_VND_UMP_CVW. I modified the view (Record definition) in App Designer to pull in the BU_PRICE_STATUS field and then modified the component interface and added this field.

When I regenerate the template in Excel, it populates the additional field fine, I select it as an input cell (along with the others I originally had) and I submit the data and return back the green OK status.

When I look online in PeopleSoft I see that the vendor data was created for the item, however the BU_PRICE_STATUS field is populated with a different value than what I specified on the upload. The default value listed on the field definition in app designer was what was populated, instead of the value I had entered for the upload.

Is there something else I did to modify for this to work? I know that when you run the Item Loader process, it uses a Message definition (IN_MST_ITM_XLS) so I wasn't sure if the message needed to be updated to? Thanks in advance.

**2/27 EDIT:**

I've found that the Component (for this component interface) - IN_MST_ITM_XLS uses a function called `PRCSITEM` within a Function library record - `FUNCLIB_INEIP` and this populates data in a staging table called `PS_ITM_VND_UMPR_EC`. I see that this table does not contain the field `BU_PRICE_STATUS` (which I didn't believe it would) so I'm thinking if the code/table can be updated to capture this field it would work. Hoping someone can suggest if I'm in the right area and what would need to be changed.

Comment: I suspect this is regarding Peoplesoft Financials? I can't find the CI in HCM or CS.

Comment: Yes that's correct Peter.